# How do people who don't use the latin alphabet use the internet?

Tags: alphabet, latin

I have a school project about how people who don't use the latin alphabet use the internet (like russians or chinese). How do they enter urls or e-mail adresses, and how do they write HTML without a latin keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here a Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#East_Asian_languages)

They have **extra keyboard layouts**, because the **internet was invented in america** everyone is using the american standarts, so the **urls are in latain** but the text on the sites they are **surfing is in their language** as our sites are in our language.

Answer (score 2):

most keyboard are QWERTY keyboard regardless of nationality, But the OS usually has ways of converting the written language. like in china for example: windows has a sub-program that runs when you type and gives you options of the Chinese character you want.

Comment: i should probably add; I once saw an arabian keyboard that was QWERTY, but it had a little red arabic character on each of the keys, so when you have a language pack installed those characters represent the place on the keyboard.